# Mysql VALUES statement performance

Tags: mysql

Since Mysql 8.0.19 it is possible to use the VALUES statement: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

I have done so in some JOIN statements and have very big performance differences which I do not understand.

If I use the VALUES statement in simple INNER JOIN like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t1 
INNER JOIN (VALUES ROW(1,2), ROW(2,3)) AS val_join
```

with about 100k values, the query gets extremely slow whereas a LEFT JOIN like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t1 
LEFT JOIN (VALUES ROW(1,2), ROW(2,3)) AS val_join
WHERE val_join.column_0 IS NULL
```

is extremely fast with more than 100k values.

Is there some background information I am missing or some basic rules when a subselect is quicker than a VALUES statement or even the usage of a SELECT with explicit values?

Comment: It's possible the optimizer is creating an index on the derived table automatically in some cases, but somehow is not doing that in all cases. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html You might get some insight by using EXPLAIN on the queries.

Comment: I would think the WHERE in the second query would greatly minimize the number of operations required.  The EXPLAIN should confirm this aspect of the two different queries.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I checked the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` statement and found this entry: `Single-row covering index lookup on asp using fk_<FOREIGN_KEY>(<ID1>=<ID2>, <ID3>=<VALUES TABLE>column_0)  (cost=1 rows=1) (actual time=0.00224..0.00224 rows=0.00109 loops=79.1e+6)` which seems to mean that something is looping 79 million times whereas in the other query the loop does only ~100k iterations. Digging deeper into that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When `JOINing`, you should include an `ON` clause to say how the two table are related.  Without `ON`, you get a `CROSS JOIN` -- which is all combinations of the rows in the two tables.  For 100K rows in each 'table', the result would have 10,000,000,000 rows -- This takes a long time to generate (and is usually not what you wanted).

Comment: Yes, I use an `ON` clause, did not mention that in the original post for simplification. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Edit your Question to include the `ON` clause.  The "simplification" destroyed the Question.  Was anything else simplified?